# How to open a new window without triggering popup blocker?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to open a file (it's an html in this case) in a new window without triggering the popup blocker.

After looking around, I've found the BrowserWindowOpener, but my issue is that I want to open dynamic content, so it doesn't work.

I've also found the Enhanced Window Opener that seems to do exactly what I want but it's for Vaadin 8.

Is there solution or at least a workaround?

For now, I've use this solution in a clickListener of button but it triggers the blocker:

```
    public void openFile() {
        File file = generateMyHTMLFile();

        StreamResource source = new StreamResource(file.getName(), () -> {
            try {

                return new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                return null;
            }
        });

        source.setContentType(fileMimeType);
        source.setCacheTime(0);
        final StreamRegistration registration = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getResourceRegistry().registerResource(source);

        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("window.open('"+registration.getResourceUri()+"', '_blank', 'height=800,width=600');");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

window.open returns WindowProxy insrance. If the popup blocker prevented window opening the open property will be false, you can return that to server and use

```
executeJs(..).then(result -> { 
   if (result.equals("false") {
      Notificaton.show("Turn off popup blocker");
   }
}
```

Comment: A lot of users don't know how to turn off the popup blocker. This is why my applications show a dialog (instead of `Notification.show`) that says "Download was blocked, but you can download the file with [this link]." And "this link" is just an `Anchor` component to your resource.